# What happened to the chat?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, area-51

What happened to the chat? It seems it's no longer accessible. Why that weird redirect?

[image]

Comment: MSE: [Chat is redirecting to Area 51 (2023 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385876/chat-stackexchange-com-redirects-to-area51-stackexchange-com)

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: @Rubén Yeah, we fixed it quickly but there was definitely some stuff happening. :)

Comment: @Catija Great job!

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible or caused by aliens. ;)

Comment: Aliens? Bah. It was badgers. And we don't need no stinking badgers.

Comment: Other than "it's a bug" what are you looking for in an answer here to your [meta-tag:support] question? Are you *really* looking for a detailed explanation (i.e. using the [meta-tag:support] tag), or are you reporting a bug (which should use the [meta-tag:bug] tag)?

Answer (score 5):

Updated on MSE as well in [Chat is redirecting to Area 51 (2023 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385876/209031)

Original issue is resolved and we have a note in our retro plans to also shore up the weird redirect when throwing errors.  The original attempt was to show the user *something* useful if they were navigating to a site after it was sunset

i.e. https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ → https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

But can accidentally get triggered when handling any other exceptions.